# Inconvenientes con proyectos Java clonados de GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, github

Soy algo nuevo en el mundo en este mundo, y la pregunta es que he decidido comenzar a usar github para guardar alli los trabajos y projectos que hago en eclipse.
Pero ahora que clone uno de estos proyectos nuevamente a mi pc veo que ahora no lo puedo compilar en eclipse (cabe aclarar que deberian estar funcionales ya que cuando los subi a github estaban bien). Lo que veo es que donde deberia aparecer el icono de package ahora aparece una carpeta normal, y pienso que eso me trata de informar algun problema.
Quisiera saber si por el solo hecho de clonar estos proyectos desde github hay que hacer algo mas para poderlos abrir en eclipse u otro IDE.

Adjunto imagen de lo que me sale cuando abro el proyecto en eclipse.
Gracias[image: Issues with eclipse]

Comment: Revisa este link https://www.lennu.net/import-git-project-into-eclipse/ espero te sirva.

Comment: Pues no funciono pero aprendí algo nuevo de eclipse. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes fijarte en los iconos para saber que está pasando, simplemente tu carpeta src no es una carpeta de código.
Para reproducir tu error crearé una carpeta en un proyecto de Java llamada `sdf`

[image: folder que no es de código]

para ello debes seleccionar la raíz de tu proyecto, darle click en new y seleccionar "source folder" o carpeta de código.

[image: tipo sourcefolder]

En el siguiente diálogo le pones la ruta de tu carpeta, en mi caso `sdf`

[image: carpeta seleccionada]

y tras completar este paso, ya se te habilitará la opción para ejecutar tus archivos si es que tienen un main.

[image: correr como aplicación de Java]